# Calling a PL SQL Function with object parameter in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

In Oracle SQL I have a type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type address_type
AS
OBJECT
(
Street VARCHAR2(100),
Road   VARCHAR2(100),
Town   VARCHAR2(100),
County VARCHAR2(100) );
```

This is used for a function, the function uses the ADDRESS_TYPE to take an answer as a parameter and returns an integer:

```
create or replace FUNCTION ADD_ADDRESS_FUNC(
    New_Address IN Address_Type )
  RETURN INTEGER
AS
  AddressID INTEGER;
BEGIN
  AddressID := ADDRESS_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  INSERT
  INTO Address VALUES
    (
      AddressID,
      New_Address.Street,
      New_Address.Road,
      New_Address.Town,
      New_Address.County
    );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(AddressID);
  RETURN AddressID;
END;
```

In my Java classes I have all connections etc & I can access other procs & functions but not this one which takes the Address object. 
In Java I create an Address object a with 4 strings, surely I can just pass this as second argument below:

```
Address a = new Address("Address 1", "Address 2", "Town", "County");
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall( "begin ? := ADD_ADDRESS_FUNC(?);end;" );
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.CHAR);
stmt.setObject(2, a);
stmt.execute ();
int memberID = stmt.getInt(1);`
```

The error message says invalid column index and it is breaking down at the setObject call. If it were a string it would be fine but the Address object isn't working.
Any help appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: The more recent JDBC (I believe Java 7 and later) have a `Struct` capability that lets you map Java objects to SQL objects.  I've never done this so I'm posting this as a comment instead of an answer since I can't give you a lot of detail.

Comment: @JimGarrison, what you refer to is the UserType and CompositeType interfaces that hibernate provides, in which you can parse the `STRUCT` object/ResultSet object as you wish. It has some methods that gets called when query.listResults() or similar is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the type in the anonymous PL/SQL block (rather than in Java) and pass in the values:

```
CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall("BEGIN ? := ADD_ADDRESS_FUNC( Address_Type(?,?,?,?)); END;");

st.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER );
st.setString( 2, "Address 1" );
st.setString( 3, "Address 2" );
st.setString( 4, "Town" );
st.setString( 5, "County" );

st.execute();
int id = st.getInt(1);
```

The alternative is that you can use [`JPublisher`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e10587/intro.htm) to generate the `Address` class so that it can be passed to/from the database.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm not the smartest at Java so I'll call the type and set the strings as above. Although it should be simple to map a Java object with a PL/SQL type, if I figure in the meantime I will post

Comment: `Connection conn ? SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getConnection().preparecal`l is deprecated

Comment: instead use: `session.doWork(connection->connection.prepareCall(..))`

Comment: @ot0 [java.sql.Connection#prepareCall( String sql )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall(java.lang.String)) is not documented as being deprecated. Also, there are no `SessionFactory` or `session` variables mentioned in my answer or the question so I do not know what framework you are using (although I would guess Hibernate) but it does not seem relevant to my answer or the question which is about pure Java and not any framework.

Comment: @MTO I assumed you were using SessionFactory` of Hibernate. It would be good, if you mentioned also how the `con` object was retrieved. In Hibernate 5 and =>, the method is deprecated. Just a bonus info for readers then.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle Functions, you can use the native sql query with Hibernate as such:

```
Query query = session.createSqlQuery("select PACKAGE.AddAdress(:STREET, :ROAD, :TOWN, :COUNTRY) as ADDRESS_ID from DUAL")
             .addScalar("ADDRESS_ID", java.sql.integer);

  query.setParameter(":STREET", "Street name")
  query.setParameter(":ROAD", "Road name")
  etc... ;

int addrId = (int) query.UniqueResult();
```

The `addScalar` method is necessary for retrieving the `ResultSet`. If your function returns an Oracle defined Type, you can say:

```
.addScalar("ADDRESS_ID", new CustomType(new OracleType()))
```

And this OracleType would be the type matching the Oracle Type.
So create a class OracleType which implements `UserType`, and override the 
method

```
nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, Sting name..){
   Object[] result = (java.sql.STRUCT) rs.getObject(names[0]).getAttributes()
}
```

This `result` will then be the object returned by query.uniqueResult as such:
`Object[] result = query.uniqueResult()` in your query method.

Comment: The question is not tagged with Hibernate - you should make it clear in your answer if you are using a framework because the question is not tagged with any and is looking for a pure Java answer unrelated to any frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Doing this with JDBC's `SQLData` SPI

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36073710/521799) shows a useful workaround where you compose your `OBJECT` type in an anonymous block. If you want to do this with a single bind variable, as you mentioned in your question, then you could create a class that implements [`java.sql.SQLData`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/SQLData.html):

```java
class Address implements SQLData {
    // Constructors, getters, and setters

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return "SCHEMA.ADDRESS_TYPE";
    }

    @Override
    public final void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName)
    throws SQLException {
        this.street = stream.readString();
        this.road = stream.readString();
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public final void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream)
    throws SQLException {
        stream.writeString(street);
        stream.writeString(road);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, you can set that value to your prepared statement:

```java
stmt.setObject(2, a);
```

If you want to read it from a `ResultSet`, you have to register that type in a `Map<String, Class<?>>`:

```java
Map<String, Class<?>> types = Map.of("SCHEMA.ADDRESS_TYPE", Address.class);
rs.getObject(position, map);
```

This approach is more viable also when you create collections of `ADDRESS_TYPE`, as you can then re-use the above class and get `Address[]` results for your collections.

#### Using a third party library

Note that [jOOQ, a third party library, has a code generator](https://blog.jooq.org/the-best-way-to-call-stored-procedures-from-java-with-jooq) for all of these object types that helps you automate all of this, including calling of procedures, etc. With jOOQ, you'd just write:

```java
AddressRecord a = new AddressRecord("Address 1", "Address 2", "Town", "County");
// configuration contains your JDBC connection
int memberId = Routines.addAddressFunc(configuration, a);
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.